# How to dynamically create multiple alerts inside mui v5 Snackbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

I am calling an API to do few actions.
I want to take the response of each action and show it inside Snackbar/alert.

I am able to show only the first response and nothing else even after iterating the messages in a map.

Here is my business logic calling the api

```
try {
      const deletedUser = await deleteUser({ username: username });
      [deletedUser.data.status.action1, deletedUser.data.status.action2].map(
        (msg) =>
          setNotify({
            isOpen: true,
            message: msg,
            type: "success",
          })
      );
    } catch (error) {}
```

setNotify will open the Snackbar with the alerts

```
import React from "react";
import { Snackbar, Alert } from "@mui/material";

import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const StyledSnackbar = styled((props) => <Snackbar {...props} />)(
  ({ theme }) => ({
    "& .MuiSnackbar-root": {
      top: theme.spacing(15),
    },
  })
);

export default function Notification(props) {
  const { notify, setNotify } = props;
  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    setNotify({
      ...notify,
      isOpen: false,
    });
  };
  return (
    <StyledSnackbar
      open={notify.isOpen}
      autoHideDuration={10000}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" }}
      onClose={handleClose}
    >
      <Alert severity={notify.type} onClose={handleClose}>
        {notify.message}
      </Alert>
    </StyledSnackbar>
  );
}
```

The only issue it's only displaying the first action and nothing else.

[Edit On Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-firefly-m6ib2)

I suspect the alerts are overlapping on top of each other Maybe we need to add some sort of AutoGrow prop

Comment: Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue for us to inspect and debug live?

Comment: added a link, let me know if there is a better way of adding sandbox code to here.

Comment: codesandbox is empty.

Comment: The linked codesandbox has a `Notification.jsx` file but it's empty. It's mostly all just the default React CSB.

Comment: sorry about that, even after I forked it, I had to save manually to push the updates. The link has been updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `notistack` as described in the [MUI doc](https://mui.com/components/snackbars/#notistack):

> This example demonstrates how to use [notistack](https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack). notistack has an
> **imperative API** that makes it easy to display snackbars, without having
> to handle their open/close state. It also enables you to **stack** them on
> top of one another (although this is discouraged by the Material
> Design guidelines).

Start by wrapping your app inside a `SnackbarProvider` component then use `useSnackbar` hook to access `enqueueSnackbar` in order to add a snackbar to the queue to be displayed:

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import { SnackbarProvider } from "notistack";
import Notification from "./Notification";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SnackbarProvider maxSnack={3}>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Dynamic Snackbar Alerts</h1>
        <Notification />
      </div>
    </SnackbarProvider>
  );
}
```

Notification.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack";

export default function Notification(props) {
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  const handleClick = async () => {
    try {
      const deletedUser = await deleteUser({ username: username });
      [deletedUser.data.status.action1, deletedUser.data.status.action2].forEach((msg) => {
          enqueueSnackbar(msg, {
            variant: "success",
            autoHideDuration: 10000,
            anchorOrigin: { vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" }
          });
      });
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  return (
    <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClick}>
      Generate Snackbar Dynamicly
    </Button>
  );
}
```

Demo:

[image: Edit sparkling-moon-ikm0o]

Comment: Thanks it works as expected, question how did you get "Edit on CodeSandbox" icons added to your answer.

Comment: `Embed` on top right -> `Other sharing options` -> `Share CodeSandbox Button` and copy the markdown